# url (i.e. a remote webdav server url) as an initial directory in openfiledialog

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

How to specify a url (i.e. a remote webdav server url) as an initial directory in openfiledialog C#. Actually if a enter the url manually everything goes fine and directory is opened in open file dialog box but if i try to automate the dialog box to get redirected to the directory (url) through code, it say "You can not open this location using this program, please try a different location".

e.g. i want to implement something like

```
 OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
 openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "http://webdavserver.abc.com/directory";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the UNC path of the web dav directory.

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"\\webdavserver.abc.com\directory";
```

Comment: do i have to write my url in the same way to make it a "UNC path"? or there is some sort of url conversion needed?

Comment: The slashes are normally reversed and the protocol dropped. See my answer for the unc path. Sometimes port numbers may be needed based on SSL etc.

Comment: well i tried it and it just directed me to "C:\Windows\System32" after a bit of wait. would there be any exception for https?